# Alfresco 5.0 Community unable to create folders within share

Tags: windows, postgresql, iis, alfresco, alfresco-share

I am trying to deploy Alfresco Community 5.0 on Windows Server 2012 R2, with IIS 8 and I have run into a little bit of a pickle. Currently, everything seems to be functioning as expected except for the creation of folders. I can add files and users, so I'm not really sure where to start.

When I try to create a new folder within the share site I am prompted with "Could not create 'new folder'. Duplicate folder name?" and I am entering a random name.

I checked the alfresco.log file and there is nothing in there.

If you need any extra information let me know.

IIS threw this exception.

Event code: 3005 
Event message: An unhandled exception has occurred. 
Event time: 3/10/2015 9:13:17 AM 
Event time (UTC): 3/10/2015 3:13:17 PM 
Event ID: 2a27fe7511504646bdc5cf85b4f428c1 
Event sequence: 90 
Event occurrence: 5 
Event detail code: 0

Application information: 
Application domain: /LM/W3SVC/1/ROOT-1-130704715600439291 
Trust level: Full 
Application Virtual Path: / 
Application Path: C:\inetpub\wwwroot\ 
Machine name: WEDNESDAY

Process information: 
Process ID: 3352 
Process name: w3wp.exe 
Account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool

Exception information: 
Exception type: HttpException 
Exception message: A potentially dangerous Request.Path value was detected from the client (:).
at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)

Request information: 
Request URL: http://wednesday/share/proxy/alfresco/api/type/cm:folder/formprocessor 
Request path: /share/proxy/alfresco/api/type/cm:folder/formprocessor 
User host address: 10.000.00.00 
User: 
Is authenticated: False 
Authentication Type: 
Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool

Thread information: 
Thread ID: 8 
Thread account name: IIS APPPOOL\DefaultAppPool 
Is impersonating: False 
Stack trace: at System.Web.HttpRequest.ValidateInputIfRequiredByConfig()
at System.Web.HttpApplication.PipelineStepManager.ValidateHelper(HttpContext context)

Comment: Can you create folders using any other interfaces? eg CMIS, WebDav, CIFS?

Comment: If you are using a browser with a debugger interface like Safari, Chrome, Firefox etc.. you can also have a look at the XHR panel or Ajax panel, sometimes more details about the error is showed in the response, and the request is also quite detailed.

Comment: I will try to use CMIS to see if it is able to. I also got this unhandled exception thrown for the first time from IIS. (above)

Answer (score 0):

asp.net 4.0 has quite extensive url validation. When Alfresco creates a folder it uses alfresco/api/type/cm:folder/formprocessor as the url. The validation rejects the use of : in url's so I added a regex function within my asp.net web.config file.

system.web>

httpRuntime requestPathInvalidCharacters="<,>,%,&,\,?" />

/system.web>

All of the other special characters are still getting validated, but I did not include ":" so now the url is allowed through.